# Is it good practice to commit docker container frequently?

Tags: docker, websphere-liberty, open-liberty

I'm using WebSphere Liberty inside. As WebSphere Liberty requires frequent xml editing, which is impossible with Dockerfile commands. I have to docker-commit the container from time to time, for others to make use of my images.

The command is like:

```
docker commit -m "updated sa1" -a "Song" $id company/wlp:v0.1
```

Colleges are doing similar things to the image, they continue to docker commit the container several times every day.

One day we're going to deploy the image on production.

Q1: Is the practice of frequent docker-committing advised?

Q2: Does it leave any potential problem behind?

Q3: Does it create an extra layer? I read the [docker-commit document](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/), which didn't mention if it creates another layer, I assume it means no.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I wouldn't use docker commit,

It seems like a really good idea but you can't reproduce the image at will like you can with a Dockerfile and you can't change the base image once this is done either, so makes it very hard to commit say for example a security patch to the underlying os base image.

If you go the full Dockerfile approach you can re-run docker build and you'll get the same image again. And you are able to change the base image.

So my rule of thumb is if you are creating a temporary tool and you don't care about reuse or reproducing the image at will then commit is convenient to use.

As I understand Docker every container image has two parts this is a group of read-only layers making up the bulk of the image and then a small layer which is writeable where any changes are committed.

When you run commit docker goes ahead and creates a new image this is the base image plus changes you made (the image created is a distinct image), it copies up the code to the thin writable layer. So a new read-only layer is not created it merely stores the deltas you make into the thin writeable layer.

Don't just take my word for it, take [Redhats advice](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2016/02/24/10-things-to-avoid-in-docker-containers/)

For clarity that article in step 5 says:

> 5) Don’t create images from running containers – In other terms, don’t
>   use “docker commit” to create an image. This method to create an image
>   is not reproducible  and should be completely avoided. Always use a
>   Dockerfile or any other S2I (source-to-image) approach that is totally
>   reproducible, and you can track changes to the Dockerfile if you store
>   it in a source control repository (git).