# Installing software in a Docker container interactively

Tags: docker

I want to create a Docker container for my scientific computing project. For this project I need to experiment with some dependencies, so it would be efficient if I access the shell of the container and install various packages and then choose some of them. Also, I want different people to reproduce my work and understand how I setup the environment. So, if possible, I want to make a file which is like a recipe for reproducing the same container. Should I just handwrite a text file listing what dependencies I chose at the end, or is there a tool in Docker which records automatically what packages are installed in the container after its creation?

Comment: `install various packages and then choose some of them` if all these can be done with command line, you can put these commands in the Dockerfile like this `RUN apt-get install xxxx` and then share this Dockefile

Comment: So should I handwrite Dockerfile that includes the selected packages? Then I might have to try the installation several times to confirm the Docker file is complete.

Comment: You can try in a container the dependencies to find the one you need. Then, once you now which are the dependencies you need, you can write the Dockerfile that install those dependencies.

Comment: @SD11 I would go build the container I need first, like what you have done. And then check your `~/.bash_history` file, identify the commands that are necessary, then manually put it in the `Dockerfile`

Comment: @SD11 It's totally reasonably to try writing a Dockerfile, `docker build .` to get an image out, run it, edit the Dockerfile, and rebuild the image; repeat until the packages you need are there.  That's probably the approach I'd take.  If you use `CMD` and not `ENTRYPOINT` to launch the main container process, you can `docker run --rm -it your-image bash` to run an interactive shell on the built image to debug it further.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any Docker tool to save the list of dependencies you install automatically. To make it easier to reproduce your exact container, you should follow the advice of @lastr2d2: record the packages you install and convert to a `RUN apt-get install -y package1 package2 ...` line in your Dockerfile. You could also use `apt list --installed` to list what you have installed, although you'll get a LOT of other packages you didn't manually install as well.

An alternative way would be to use `docker commit` to save the state of a running container and pushing the image to Docker Hub. The `commit` commands will create a Docker image of the current state of your container. [These docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit) provide details about this command.

> **Important Note:** If you choose to do this, please read the warnings about using `docker commit`. In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51763737/4676641), the author points out **you should not use docker commit at all** because the container isn't completely reproducible.

If you've read this warning and still want to use docker commit, here's an example:

```sh
# run the container to install packages
$ docker run -it --name container-to-commit ubuntu:20.04 /bin/bash

## inside Docker terminal session
# install packages here
$ apt-get update
$ apt-get install gcc ...
```

To save the container, you need to keep it running and run `docker commit CONTAINER_ID` in another terminal. For example:

```sh
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE            COMMAND     CREATED          STATUS          PORTS     NAMES
a26092c038ab   ubuntu:20.04   "/bin/bash"   56 seconds ago   Up 55 seconds             container-to-commit

# commit the image with the label "username/container-name"
# username should be your Docker Hub username if you choose to distribute on Docker Hub
$ docker commit a26092c038ab username/container-name:v1

$ docker images
REPOSITORY                   TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
username/container-name       v1     4752ae644acf   5 seconds ago     523MB
```

Comment: "Not completely reproducible" --> you shouldn't really ever use `docker commit` at all.